# Does anyone has ideas of managing multiple Jenkins Masters from a centralized server?

Tags: jenkins

I have 10 Jenkins Master instances, but I would like to know if there is a way to manage all the Jenkins at once

example: upgrades, plugins, managing credentials

Answer (score 0):

You can manage jenkins server using the ansible playbook.

Install ansible on one machine, create ssh keys and put it on to all the jenkins masters. This way ansible can talk to jenkins masters using ssh passwordless mechanism.

That way you can upgrade packages on to the Jenkins Masters using ansible-playbook. Below is the code :

```
- name: install the latest version of Apache
  yum:
    name: httpd
    state: latest
```

For jenkins plugin installation, ansible provides jenkins_plugin module. Sample code is :

```
- name: Install plugin without its dependencies
  jenkins_plugin:
    name: build-pipeline-plugin
    with_dependencies: no
```

You can check out the documentation here : [jenkins_plugin – Add or remove Jenkins plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/jenkins_plugin_module.html)

There is no Rest API call for creating Credential in Jenkins but there is a way that you can utilize with the combination of curl and ansible. Below is the article you can refer :

[add Jenkins credentials with curl or Ansible](https://getintodevops.com/blog/how-to-add-jenkins-credentials-with-curl-or-ansible)

Merge all the code into one Ansible Playbook and you are good.